# Add a Month Column to a Date Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I'm working with a dataframe that contains the next columns

```
DATE       Months  New_Date
2020-07-03    1    2020-08-01
2022-05-06    6    2022-11-01
2020-06-23    4    2020-10-01
```

I need to add the values (months) in the column 'months' to the column date and get a new date.
I've been researching and find some solutions like this

```
self.df['New_Date'] = (
self.df["DATE"].values.astype("datetime64[M]") 
+ self.df["Months"].values.astype("timedelta64[M]")
)
```

But as you can see, I get the correct month but the day it's the first of that month and not the correct day of the date.

I am trying to not to use apply & offset or apply & relativedelta cause I think that the efficiency of my script won't be good. So I want to know if exists a way to use relativedelta or offset without using apply (maybe vectorizing but I couldn't figure out how to) or if you know a different way to get the correct result.

Thanks in advance, I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for:

```
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])
tdf = np.vectorize(lambda x:np.timedelta64(x,'M'))
df['NewDate'] = (df['DATE'] + tf(df['Months'])).dt.date
```

Comment: Thank you! It works partially, I just change the 2nd line  for ```tdf = np.vectorize(lambda x:relativedelta(months=x))``` cause in some months there is a difference in the days, but using relative delta solves this issue and I get the exact date. Thank you again m8!